# With a negative Strength value, how much damage can I do?

Tags: combat, unisystem, all-flesh-must-be-eaten

When skipping through the *All Flesh Must Be Eaten* rulebook, I noticed that you can create PCs with negative strength values (e.g., children). As hand weapons do damage based on that strength value, they could actually produce negative damage results:

```
D4(2) x Strength
```

I couldn't find anything in the AFMBE rulebook or errata that prevented this. I think I'll go and just ignore the multiplier for negative values, making it effectively 1. Or maybe it should be 0, as a character with such low strength can't possibly do any form of damage using a hand weapon.

Are there any rules for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a rule for calculating Secondary Attributes based off Attributes that have a zero or negative value. It seems reasonable—although doesn't appear explicitly, as far as I can tell—to do the same for damage when multiplying by the Strength Attribute.

> *All Flesh Must Be Eaten (Revised), page 33*
>
> Some characters have Attributes of 0 or even in the negative numbers. These levels represent Attributes that are far below average. Special rules for determining Secondary Attributes are required in this case. **When dealing with low Primary Attributes, treat them as being equal to 1 for determination purposes.** **If the Attribute is negative, then subtract it from the resulting
>   Secondary Attribute.** ... The special rule for treating 0s and negative numbers in Secondary Attributes only applies to those that involve multiplication

Comment: I should point out that for negative numbers, this rule goes on to subtract the number from the result - for Life Points with a negative Strength, for example, you'd calculate Life Points as if you had Strength 1 but then subtract your Strength from the final result.  This should probably also apply to weapon damage - a D4 x Str weapon should probably do 1d4 - Str.  Deciding whether the minimum should be 1 or 0 is entirely up to you.

Comment: @gatherer818 An excellent point! Answer updated.